# How to get realtime data using JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for an efficient way to populate a div with real time data.

this is what I am using right now.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {                  
            setInterval(function() {
                var datatyp = 'A';
                var db = 0;
                var byte = 4;
                var bit = 7;
                $('#output2').load('plc.php?function=read-bit', {'datatyp':datatyp, 'db':db, 'byte':byte, 'bit':bit});
            }, 100)              
        });
```

Is there a better more efficient way of doing this? Also if I set the interval to 100ms like in the example, will this be bad in any way for the server?

Side note: This will run on a home network.

Thanks!

Comment: As long as your server is healthy and the data isn't huge you should be OK.

Comment: What kind of data would you like to display, that such a frequent refresh rate is required?

Comment: Yes there is a better way of doing this, look into nodejs for realtime. Ajax  isn't exactly realtime.

Comment: Not an answer, but my suggestion is to look towards websockets

Comment: With this I am actually just checking one bit...if it is set or not. I use this for a feedback of set outputs on my plc. If 1 bit is set, I want to monitor this.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at push data. With that you can push data from the server to the client instead of pulling.

If you do that, you will only strain the server when there's new data.

NodeJS with socket.io could be an example of this.

Otherwise you could look for some push-service like pusher.com

Comment: Do you happen to have an example for this?

Comment: http://socket.io/ - On the fronpage there's an example on both a server and a client. For more info there's a lot of tutorials to get you started with nodejs and connect.io :)

Comment: I checked out pusher. But I'm unsure how to trigger an activity once a variable has been changed...I have no experience with pusher or websockets what so ever, this looks daunting

Comment: It could be something like everytime you put something in your database that the user(s) should be notified.
It may look dauting, but from your question and my in my opition, it's worth the read and the time :)

Answer (score 0):

Making a request every 100ms is a *lot* of requests. Are you sure you need updates that fast? Even for a local server.

Secondly, when making consistent AJAX requests, it's better to fire a new request with `setTimeout` on completion of the previous request. That way you don't end up with potentially hundreds of queued requests if the server responses start to slow down. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    loadData();              
}); 

function loadData() {
    var datatyp = 'A';
    var db = 0;
    var byte = 4;
    var bit = 7;
    $('#output2').load('plc.php?function=read-bit', { 'datatyp': datatyp, 'db': db, 'byte': byte, 'bit': bit}, function() {
        setTimeout(loadData, 100);
    });
}
```

Comment: What If I need multiple of these scripts with different variables to monitor different bits?